# How to compare 2 expressions regardless of form?

Tags: formatting

trying to do that:

```
In[15]:= FullForm[FullForm[1/a^2]]==FullForm[Power[a,-2]]
```

result is following

```
Out[15]= FullForm[Power[a, -2]] == Power[a, -2]
```

I would expect it to be true

Also, consider this session:

```
In[16]:= FullForm[FullForm[1/a^2]]                                                                                                           

Out[16]//FullForm= FullForm[Power[a, -2]]

In[17]:= Power[a,-2]                                                                                                                         

          -2
Out[17]= a

In[18]:= Out[16]==Out[17]                                                                                                                    

Out[18]= True
```

Is there a way to evaluate expression the exact same way interactive interpreter does it before putting into `Out`?..

Comment: It is really not clear to me what you want to accomplish here. Anyway, you would want to use `===` to compare those forms and force evaluation. That returns `FullForm[FullForm[1/a^2]] === FullForm[Power[a, -2]]` returns `False`. Consider also that `FullForm`, like most (all?) of the `*Form` functions, acts as a wrapper, which affects display *but not evaluation*.